# Why isn't XMLBeans able to parse my valid XML documents?

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I have an XML schema that defines a bunch of complex types that are various commands, responses, and events.

As a particular example, I have a Response complex type that consists of elements that are common to all responses, regardless of type. Then, I have various specific types of responses. Some responses don't add any other elements beyond those in the Response complex type while others are extremely complicated and contain various other elements that may be complex or simple:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:Command" targetNamespace="urn:Command" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="0.0.5.0">
    <xs:complexType name="Response">
        <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>...</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="commandID"/>
            <xs:element ref="responseToID"/>
            <xs:element ref="commandStatus"/>
            <xs:element ref="creationTime"/>
            <xs:element ref="completionTime"/>
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
...
<xs:complexType name="SpecificResponse">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>...</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Response"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
...
```

When I receive a SpecificResponse, which contains an xs:extension of Response along with a number of other fields, the XML actually looks like:

```
<Response xsi:type="SpecificResponse" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Command {file path}" xmlns="urn:Response" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <commandID>...</commandID>
  <responseToID>...</responseToID>
  <commandStatus>...</commandStatus>
  <creationTime>...</creationTime>
  <completionTime>...</completionTime>
</Response>
```

When I use the `SpecificResponse.Factory.parse(...)` or `SpecificResponseDocument.Factory.parse(...)` method on this XML, it fails since "Element Response is not a valid SpecificResponse document or a valid substitution". In this particular example, it's not that much of an issue - having an instance of a SpecificResponse or a SpecificResponseDocument doesn't add any new methods for me to call, since all of the fields exist in both. However, in instances where DifferentSpecificResponse contains additional elements, it's problematic. Plus, I'd rather have the more accurate type information when I add them to a data structure that can contain anything that extends Response.

The complete document validates in external tools against the schema. Even though it has all of the elements of a SpecificResponse (which are not defined in a Response element), it appears that having an xsi:type of SpecificResponse makes the XML valid (is this an incorrect assumption?). However, it also looks like XMLBeans is looking at the root element and not the xsi:type of the XML that I'm trying to parse.

So far, the solution that I've found is to parse the response using `ResponseDocument.Factory.parse(...)`, then call the `getResponse()` function on it, and then type cast it into the appropriate specific response. This seems very clumsy to me, but once I'm done casting, I can use the XMLBeans accessor and mutator methods, along with its class hierarchy (which is what I would expect - a SpecificResponse is a subclass of Response). Is there a better way of handling this, assuming that the source of the message can not be changed to send the XML `<SpecificResponse...` and must continue to send `<Response xsi:type="SpecificResponse"...`

Comment: I'm guessing there's a namespace issue.  You'd need to post a sample document and appropriate sections of the XSD. Can you create a minimal XSD with one or two element definitions that exhibits this behavior and include it?

Comment: @CharlesForsythe Snipped out example provided. It's not the most detail, but probably the best I can do.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Have you tried changing `schemaLocation` to `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`?  I believe that is the recommending XSD reference to use when you are not using fully qualified tag names (i.e. when you do not specify namespace on each tag in the doc).

Comment: @CharlesForsythe I can't really do anything about that. I could change a text file that's used in testing, but the other application that generates the XML responses can't easily be modified. Considering that I used the XMLBeans generation tool on the XSDs, it contains them. Could I have the XMLBeans libraries ignore that value when parsing somehow?

Comment: @CharlesForsythe `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` is for when you're not using namespaces at all.  In this case the response _is_ in a namespace and so are all its children, due to the `xmlns="..."`

Comment: It looks like [this blog post about the design of XMLBeans](http://davidbau.com/archives/2003/12/18/the_design_of_xmlbeans_part_3.html) is related. I need to read and fully understand it, though.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks for the clarification.  I wasn't sure about that.